# Ajuda com função PL SQL

Tags: sql, banco-de-dados, oracle, pl-sql

Olá!

Estou desenvolvendo uma função que recebe como parâmetro o cliente e o valor e verifica se o cliente tem limite de crédito para efetivar uma venda, porém ao chamar a função não está retornando corretamente o resultado.

```
    CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION F_LIMITE_CREDITO(
    P_NOME IN TB_CLIENTES.NOME%TYPE
) 
RETURN NUMBER
IS
    P_LIMITE NUMBER;
BEGIN

    SELECT LIMITE INTO P_LIMITE
    FROM TB_CLIENTES
    WHERE NOME = P_NOME;

    RETURN P_LIMITE;
END F_LIMITE_CREDITO;
/

DECLARE
C_NOME VARCHAR2 := TB_CLIENTES.NOME;
BEGIN
    IF F_LIMITE_CREDITO (C_NOME) < 10 THEN
        dbms_output.put_line("LIMITE INDISPONIVEL");
    END IF;
END;
/
```

gostaria da ajuda de vocês pois estou iniciando em PL.

Comment: Seu select retorna algum resultado? acredito que seria interessante buscar pelo ID do cliente ao invés do nome.

Comment: Retorna a coluna nome e limite de credito porém com o valor zerado.

Comment: A tabela clientes tem as colunas `cliente_id, nome e limite`

Comment: Comparou e resultado da function com a execução avulsa do select ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Eu recomendo a você utilizar CLIENT_ID como parâmetro da função, e não NOME, pois caso haja duas pessoas com mesmo nome sua função vai dar erro (SELECT INTO só pode retornar uma linha).

Você tem também que colocar uma EXCEPTION para o caso onde o SELECT não encontrar o cliente.

Para o seu código tal como está hoje, faltou passar um nome válido para filtrar, por exemplo:

```
DECLARE
    C_NOME TB_CLIENTES.NOME%TYPE := 'Mario';
BEGIN
    IF F_LIMITE_CREDITO (C_NOME) < 10 THEN
        dbms_output.put_line('LIMITE INDISPONIVEL');
    END IF;
END;
/
```

E você também pode fazer assim direto no SELECT:

```
SELECT NOME,
           CASE WHEN F_LIMITE_CREDITO(NOME) < 10 THEN 'LIMITE INDISPONIVEL' 
                ELSE 'APROVADO'
           END AS SITUACAO_LIMITE
    FROM TB_CLIENTES;
```

Bom, eu re-escreveria sua função assim: [eu usei -1 para erro, mas você poderia substituir por RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR (documentação [neste link](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/lnpls/plsql-error-handling.html#GUID-48F88C61-8CE9-4821-91CB-48A8F1BC09E1) para tratar o erro na própria função)]:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION F_LIMITE_CREDITO
    ( P_ID IN TB_CLIENTES.CLIENTE_ID%TYPE ) 
RETURN NUMBER IS
     P_LIMITE NUMBER;
BEGIN

    IF P_ID IS NULL
    THEN
        RETURN -1;
    END IF;

    SELECT LIMITE INTO P_LIMITE
    FROM TB_CLIENTES
    WHERE CLIENTE_ID = P_ID;

    RETURN P_LIMITE;

    EXCEPTION WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND
    THEN
          RETURN -1;

END F_LIMITE_CREDITO;
/
```

Para chamar:

```
SELECT NOME,
       CASE WHEN F_LIMITE_CREDITO(CLIENTE_ID) = -1 THEN 'ERRO'
            WHEN F_LIMITE_CREDITO(CLIENTE_ID) < 10 THEN 'LIMITE INDISPONIVEL' 
            ELSE 'APROVADO'
       END AS SITUACAO_LIMITE
FROM TB_CLIENTES;
```

Comment: Fernando, usei seu exemplo e retornou corretamente.
Obrigado pela ajuda.